# XGBoost learning rate "rescaling according to size of trees". Explanation

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, learning-rate, open-source, c++

I'm trying to understand the impact of the learning rate parameter in XGBoost. I started inspecting the [source code](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost). In [this file](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/d62daa0b32b8a29f36b83318a3c690d397c97f6f/src/tree/updater_quantile_hist.cc), I found the following lines

```cpp
void QuantileHistMaker::Update(HostDeviceVector<GradientPair> *gpair, DMatrix *dmat,
                               common::Span<HostDeviceVector<bst_node_t>> out_position,
                               const std::vector<RegTree *> &trees) {
  // rescale learning rate according to size of trees
  float lr = param_.learning_rate;
  param_.learning_rate = lr / trees.size();

  // build tree
  const size_t n_trees = trees.size();
  if (!pimpl_) {
    pimpl_.reset(new Builder(n_trees, param_, dmat, task_, ctx_));
  }

  size_t t_idx{0};
  for (auto p_tree : trees) {
    auto &t_row_position = out_position[t_idx];
    this->pimpl_->UpdateTree(gpair, dmat, p_tree, &t_row_position);
    ++t_idx;
  }

  param_.learning_rate = lr;
}
```

My interpretation of this code is that XGBoost trains $n$ trees $f_1, f_2, \dots, f_n$ with learning rate $\eta$, and predicts according to $f = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{\eta}{i} f_i$.

Is my understandig correct? I would greatly appreciate some help from those familiar with the codebase.

Comment: A question on the same topic exists in XGBoost Discuss https://discuss.xgboost.ai/t/question-about-scaling-learning-rate-in-source-code/2762